# Is there a way to do a word search for values of one column in another column?

Tags: sql, pgadmin

I have a database that contains columns that are text fields (strings, a few sentences long) and columns that are shorter strings (eg: college majors).  Is there any way I can use the 'LIKE' function in SQL to search whether one of the values of the College Major column appears in another column?

I don't want to write out each of the college majors as a string since there are over 100.

Comment: Please explain in brief with your code, so it would be easy to understand and solve your problem as well.

Comment: So you want to check all possible combinations of short strings agaisnt long strings, is that right?

Comment: Could you please provide some test data for better understanding. It is unclear from the question

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Something like

```
where bigdatacolumn like '%' + computer_major + '%'
```

Since you said, other column contains few lines (`Text` column), you probably want to consider using [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) instead of using `LIKE` operator

Comment: as a note, you could also do a join on the fields.  Also as a note, string comparisons are going to be slow, especially using like.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus, yes joining the column a good idea but you will have to specify the same `like` condition on `JOIN ON` clause

Comment: yes, I wasn't trying to imply otherwise, just adding another means to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use The ANY operator to compare in an array as shown in the below query.

```
select * from staff where department ILIKE ANY ( ARRAY['AUT%', '%COM%' ,'SP%' ] :: TEXT[] );
```